# Getting value from one action method to other inside same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two action methods inside a controller. With the help of first action method, I am fetching the required data from database and I need to get this fetched data inside the second action method. I need to achieve this without passing any parameter to the second method. I don’t know how to do this as I am new to MVC.

Method 1:

```
public ActionResult GetData(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string folderPath = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BackupPath"]);
    List<string> invalidRecords = new List<string>();
    string backupFileName = FileUpload.BackupFile(file, folderPath);
    invalidRecords = File.GetDataFromDB(backupFileName);
    List<DataVM> lst = serviceData.GetAllData();
    return View(lst);
}
```

Method 2:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetInvalidRecords()
{
    List<string> InvalidVehicleId = InvalidRecords;
    return new JsonResult { Data = InvalidRecords };
}
```

Comment: eh? Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You need to fetch it in same request or next request.

Comment: The better question here is - why would you not want to pass a parameter to the second method? You can put your stuff in the session or tempdata with .Keep() method but duh...

Comment: Well....we were asked to achieve this scenario but from the above comments I feel this is not a good approach to go with. I will look for another way around.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. :)

Comment: Great Decision.... Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a session variable to hold the value of your 'lst' variable in your 'GetData' action:

```
Session["data"] = lst
```

Then you can retrieve it as follows and cast it to the appropriate type:

```
var data = (List<DataVM>)Session["data"]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: I think in this case session is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData as well

```
TempData["Name of Tempdata variable "]= File.GetDataFromDB(backupFileName)
```

and in other action you can recieve it

```
var getdatafromanotherAction= TempData["Name of Tempdata variable"]
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call both action methods in single call, You can use
return RedirectToAction("GetInvalidRecords") in the first method. Also, you can create a class level private variable _listdata. Set it in first method , get in second method.

If you want to keep data between the 2 calls, use Tempdata.Keep and Tempdata.Peek but you need to make sure that call for second method immediately follows first method. Tempdata works between 2 requests only unless you extend its duration by using .Keep and .Peek once more.

If these two methods are to be called few calls apart, you can use session variable to keep the data.

Alternatively, you can keep the parameter of the second method call optional. So, it won't hurt other calls of the jsonresult method. Inside the method, you can check whether parameter is empty or not.

Comment: What is the need of private variable in first case?? There also you can use temp data.

Comment: She has not mentioned whether she wants to call both in same request or different requests. Also, she does not want to pass parameter to second method. Within the same call, you can hold that data in class level private variable.

Comment: Tempdata is internally a session variable which will be held till in the running server memory till the next request atleast. Scope of private variable will end with the same call for the initialized object.

Comment: It will never held in server till next request. It will be cleared on completion of single request.   I accept with scope but tell me when that will collected by GC

Comment: That's what i mentioned earlier, for the case when both methods are to be called one after another in the same request, private variable can be used. It is not supposed to hold between requests. For the case, if the user is going to make 2 different requests for 2 methods, tempdata can be used. Private variable will get garbage collected with controller class object getting garbage collected.

Comment: If you use temp data then there is no overhead for GC.  It will be removed on completion of request.

Comment: Yup, but that is on completion of subsequent request. Default tempdata provider uses session to store values. In case of private variable, we are not storing anything in session for the same request calling 2 methods although it can be used there as well but you will require typecasting data.